fusing inner lists within list function to return highest possible integer dynamic programming
new to programming and currently trying to challenge myself and learn dynamic programming. I have this question to implement a function that takes an array and outputs the 'highest cuteness' of the possible inner lists within the array.
The inner lists represent a creature that can only fuse with adjacent lists (adjacent creatures, if creature on edge of lists, can only fuse with creatures on right or left, no wrap around). Initially I created a greedy algorithm to solve because i thought making optimal choice at each step would work, but alas does not. So i turned to a dynamic approach, but I'm having trouble converting the greedy alg into a dynamic one.
The array may contain one or thousands of creatures and at the end of the recursion, there should only be one creature left, through fusing with all other creatures within the list.
An array of creatures may look like this: "creatures = [0, 255, 0.38], [0.38, 836, 0.36], [0.36, 152, 0.79], [0.79, 38, 0.82], [0.82, 303, 0]]", where the left and right values indicate the affinity and the middle value is the cuteness of the creature.
The equation for the new cuteness is:
cuteness_score = fitmons[i][1] * fitmons[i][2] + fitmons[i+1][1] * fitmons[i+1][0].
The new creature as a result of the fusion takes the left affinity of creature1, the new cuteness of fusing the creatures and the right affinity of creature2.
Any help would be high appreciated !!
This is my greedy approach:
def fuse(fitmons: list[list]) -> int:
    CUTENESS = 1
    LEFT_AFF = 0
    RIGHT_AFF = 2
    INDEX = 3
    NEXT_INDEX = 4

    array = fitmons
    while (len(array) != 1):
        max_cute = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        cuteness = 0

        for i in array:
            print(array)
            index = array.index(i)
            next_index = index+1

            if index == len(array) - 1:
                break

            cuteness = (array[index][CUTENESS] * array[index][RIGHT_AFF]) + (array[next_index][LEFT_AFF] * array[next_index][CUTENESS])


            if cuteness > max_cute[1]:
                max_cute = (array[index][LEFT_AFF], cuteness, array[next_index][RIGHT_AFF], index, next_index)

        #now we want to remove the two elements we merged and add the new array
        new_insert = [max_cute[LEFT_AFF], int(max_cute[CUTENESS]), max_cute[RIGHT_AFF]]

        array.remove(array[max_cute[NEXT_INDEX]])
        array.remove(array[max_cute[INDEX]])
        array.insert(max_cute[INDEX], new_insert)
        
        
    return array

print(fuse([[0, 255, 0.38], [0.38, 836, 0.36], [0.36, 152, 0.79], [0.79, 38, 0.82], [0.82, 303, 0]]))

And currently, this is what i'm working with in DP:
"
def fuse(fitmons: list[list]) -> int:

    def get_cuteness_score(i: int, j: int, memo: dict) -> int:
        if (i, j) in memo:
            return memo[(i, j)]
    
        if i == j:
            return 0
    
        max_score = 0
    
        for k in range(i, j):
            left_aff = fitmons[k][LEFT_AFF]
            right_aff = fitmons[k][RIGHT_AFF]
    
            print("Memo: ", memo)
            print("Fitmons: ", fitmons)
    
            score = (
    
                get_cuteness_score(i, k, memo)
                + get_cuteness_score(k + 1, j, memo)
                + fitmons[k][CUTENESS] * fitmons[k][RIGHT_AFF]
                + fitmons[k + 1][CUTENESS] * fitmons[k + 1][LEFT_AFF]  # Corrected this line
            )
    
    
    
            max_score = int(max(max_score, score))
    
        memo[(i, j)] = max_score
        return max_score
    
if not fitmons:
    return 0

CUTENESS = 1
LEFT_AFF = 0
RIGHT_AFF = 2

memo = {}
return get_cuteness_score(0, len(fitmons) - 1, memo)

fitmons = [[0, 255, 0.38], [0.38, 836, 0.36], [0.36, 152, 0.79], [0.79, 38, 0.82], [0.82, 303, 0]] print(fuse(fitmons))".


A greedy algorithm is not guaranteed to give an optimal result. My general approach to this type of problem is to come up with a naive algorithm first, then look for alternatives with better performance. That way, I know what results to expect from a more sophisticated approach.

Are we to assume the left and right affinities are > 0 and < 1?

I can't get your greedy program to run. I keep getting TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable. In your example, the right affinity of the ith element is equal to the left affinity of the i+1th element. Is this always true? Is this a coding challenge from some website? Please provide a link if so.

Yes affirnties between 0.1 and 0.9 inclusive, otherwise 0 if on edge of list.

I've only written a couple of 'dynamic programming' programs, so I found this an interesting challenge. I did like I said in the comments, and wrote a naive brute force algorithm first to have something to compare results with. I solved the example in the question easily enough with an optimum value of 438.5347536. The mixed use of decimals and integers is an issue for serious work, but I elected to just ignore that for now. For a reliable optimisation, the arithmetic calculations should be exact, but they are not in my program as they are subject to floating point rounding issues.
As it is often said, 'Brute Force Doesn't Scale, At ALL!!'. I have to say my program was pretty crudely written in PHP, and it took minutes to solve for 12 elements. Its computational complexity is something like O((n-1)!) for n creatures. The problem doesn't immediately look like DP can help, as usually with DP problems, you find a max for x+1 from knowing the max for x, or something along those lines. One needs to find the optimal sub-problem, to make DP viable. In this case, knowing the optimal way to fuse the first x elements does not straight off give the optimal way to fuse the first x+1 elements.
There may be a better way to do it, but I did it by storing the optimal cutenesses of the subarray starting at index i with length l in a 2D array C[i][l]. Then you can use these to find
C[i][l] = max_{j=1 to l-1}(fuse(C[i][j], C[i+j][l-j]))

The DP program solves for a thousand elements in a couple of minutes. I'm quite sure it would be significantly faster if I rewrote it in c. Anyway, it shows that it is feasible to solve this problem for thousands of elements in reasonable time. What the OP's performnce targets are though, are not currently available in their question.
Just for fun, see if you can solve the following case. I find the performance of DP solutions quite magical when they work. I get an optimal value of 3617.589450988 after fusing of the element pair with lower indices
0,0,0,3,2,1,3,2,2,3,2,1,0,6,5,4,3,2,1,2,5,5,4,3,2,2,1,0,4,3,2,1,1,1,1,5,4,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,3,2,2,1,0

These are the randomly generated 'creatures'. The DP program solves it in milliseconds.
[0,338,0.17]
[0.17,556,0.19]
[0.19,961,0.71]
[0.71,308,0.88]
[0.88,886,0.42]
[0.42,299,0.49]
[0.49,938,0.17]
[0.17,667,0.76]
[0.76,278,0.39]
[0.39,191,0.42]
[0.42,1,0.55]
[0.55,975,0.89]
[0.89,107,0.12]
[0.12,893,0.9]
[0.9,884,0.5]
[0.5,977,0.51]
[0.51,790,0.46]
[0.46,486,0.2]
[0.2,807,0.17]
[0.17,119,0.39]
[0.39,55,0.89]
[0.89,94,0.84]
[0.84,413,0.7]
[0.7,999,0.41]
[0.41,875,0.46]
[0.46,222,0.3]
[0.3,471,0.12]
[0.12,776,0.84]
[0.84,586,0.9]
[0.9,38,0.56]
[0.56,196,0.17]
[0.17,426,0.36]
[0.36,39,0.1]
[0.1,109,0.22]
[0.22,659,0.78]
[0.78,347,0.69]
[0.69,467,0.83]
[0.83,667,0.31]
[0.31,756,0.17]
[0.17,611,0.14]
[0.14,879,0.11]
[0.11,440,0.51]
[0.51,637,0.38]
[0.38,593,0.34]
[0.34,912,0.69]
[0.69,721,0.9]
[0.9,321,0.45]
[0.45,81,0.27]
[0.27,82,0.7]
[0.7,597,0]


This makes sense, it is an interesting problem, I found it in an old Algorithms textbook at my local library and thought it peculiar. Just out of interest, could I see your implementation, I've been working on it the last few days and i get different return values each time, so i'm not too sure what i'm doing wrong.

@romynichols Could you provide the book title and author? I don't know python so I can't help you there. I still can't even run your programs. My PHP program is not currently of a quality I want to expose to the SO community, so I'd prefer to keep it to myself at this point. I might get round to rewriting it in c at some stage to see how the performance differs. Maybe then I could post it on GitHub or something.
